# opencv and cv2.so/libcv2.so setup for python

Tags: python, opencv

I installed opencv 2.4.8 on my raspberry-pi. But i am not able to locate cv2.so /libcv2.so so that whenever i import i get error as **cv2** not found. Is there a way to download theese packages to use in python. How to set this up?